# Does DataFlow Object need to be locked if same object used in different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, tpl-dataflow

I am using the same dataflow objects in different threads.
Do  locks have to be used on the dataflow objects or are the objects automatically thread safe?
For example:

```
// Dataflow object defined
ITargetBlock<FileQueueItem> producerChange = new BufferBlock<FileQueueItem>();

TransformBlock<FileQueueItem, FileQueueItem> transformBlock = new TransformBlock<FileQueueItem, FileQueueItem>(
            f => 
            {/*...*/});

ActionBlock<FileQueueItem> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<FileQueueItem>(f=>
            {/*...*/});

// DataFlow objects linked
producerChange .LinkTo(transformBlock );
transformBlock .LinkTo(actionBlock);


// DataFlow object method where datadlow objects used in a thread
public async void OnRunDataFlow(FileQueueItem f)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var sent = await producerChange.SendAsync(f);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the same object used by different threads concurrently, or sequentially?

Comment: The public async void OnRunDataFlow(FileQueueItem f) is and event handler. Everytime the event is fired the OnRunDataFlow is called. In Iv OnRunDataFlow(FileQueueItem f) event handler a new task is ran to use a class variable target dataflow object to send the message. The source dataflow object and the other dataflow objects linked to the source are also all class variables. Now in one of the linked dataflow object that same target dataflow object maybe send the message again. It sees like that target dataflow object needs a lock on it, THAT  IS what i am not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

No, the objects are not automatically thread-safe. In case your dataflow setup  allows the same object to be used by more than one threads concurrently, you'll have to synchronize the access to the objects using the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement appropriately, otherwise the state of your objects might become corrupted.